# SOCK_STREAM is working fine, but PHP SOCK_RAW is not. Anyone have any example?

Tags: php, sockets

So I have tested socket with this piece of code, it is working **fine** (SOCK_STREAM)

```
   <?php    
        set_time_limit(0);
        
        $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket \n");
        $result = socket_bind($sock, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket \n");
        
        $result = socket_listen($sock, 3) or die("Dould not set up socket listener \n");
        echo "Listening for connection \n";
        
        // LOOP FOREVER
        do {
                $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die ("Could not accept incoming connection \n");
                $msg = socket_read($accept, 100000) or die("Could not read input \n");
        
                echo "Client says: " . $msg . "\n\n\n";
        
        } while(true);
        
        socket_close($accept, $sock);
```

But the problem is when i try to change the `socket_create()` to `SOCK_RAW`

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1) or die("Could not create socket \n");
```

or

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0) or die("Could not create socket \n");
```

or

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, getprotobyname('icmp')) or die("Could not create socket \n");
```

I have the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [10045]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced in C:\xampp\htdocs\wialon php script\server.php on line 10

Warning: socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [10045]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced in C:\xampp\htdocs\wialon php script\server.php on line 10
Dould not set up socket listener
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `socket_listen()` (and by extension, `socket_accept()`) with RAW sockets. They are only meaningful for connection-oriented (ie: TCP, etc) sockets. The PHP documentation even says so:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php

> `socket_listen()` is applicable only to sockets of type `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php

> After the socket `socket` has been created using `socket_create()`, bound to a name with `socket_bind()`, **and told to listen for connections with `socket_listen()`**, this function will accept incoming connections on that socket.

Comment: ok now i understand that socket_listen() only available for SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET

Comment: but now can i write the code with SOCK_RAW

After the socket socket has been created using socket_create(), bound to a name with socket_bind(), and told to listen for connections with socket_listen(), this function will accept incoming connections on that socket

From this statement, i cannot use socket_listen anymore

Do you have any example code, because i cannot find any working ones and I am struggling with it. 

Sorry for the lack of knowledge. I am new to this

Comment: Correct, you CANNOT use `socket_listen()` and `socket_accept()` with RAW sockets. Nor do you need to. After `socket_bind()`, simply enter your `socket_read()` loop, using the RAW socket as the socket to read from. To differentiate clients, you will have to analyze the IP header in each message that is read.